# Ubuntu Software Center does not start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 20.04

The Ubuntu Software Center does not start in Ubuntu 20.04. This is new and did not occur after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: That worked - thank you!